# How to raise event in a component which is created using DCL loadnexttolocation()?

Tags: angular

I have a parent component which loads a child component using DCL loadnextto location>.

When I click on a button in the parent component I want to raise the event in Child component.

Earlier I used to raise the event using viewchild but now it is showing an error, I used to raise events in child components from parent using viewchild in beta.12.

Somebody tell me what changes should I make to raise the events in the child component in beta-16.

This is my demo http://plnkr.co/edit/LKWr27zwa2IutryOStgR?p=preview

```
@ViewChild(Child) childcomp: Child;
//This is by button event used to raise an event in child component
    GetData(){
        this.childcomp.raiseEvent();
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to access `cmpRef.instance` that you get from `loadNextToLocation()`

```
  ngAfterViewInit() { 
    this.dcl.loadNextToLocation(Child, this.viewport)
    .then(cmpRef => {
      console.log(cmpRef);
      this.cmpRef = cmpRef;
    });
  }
```

```
<button (click)="cmpRef.instance.raiseEvent()">Button</button>
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/cpqB7DtdfAW3xeNA3Oxz?p=preview)

`DynamicComponentLoader` is deprecated. See [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468) for an example how to use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` instead.

Comment: Thanks Gunter...now i got it